# Grid of calendars border dimension

Tags: javascript, html

I am using jQuery to generate a grid of calendars.

My js code so far:

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        'numberOfMonths': 12,
        'showButtonPanel': true
    })
});
```

In my html:

```html
<div class="datePickerClass"></div>
```

In my css:

```css
.ui-datepicker-group:nth-child(5n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

So basically I am generating 5 calendars on a row. The problem is that the border of the calendars is way to big. Is there any way I can fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your css:

```
.ui-datepicker.ui-datepicker-multi {
  width: fit-content !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried your options but I am receiving a warning saying that fit-content is not a valid value for width property. And now all my calendars are on a single column

Comment: Something strange. Here I prepare a working codepen https://codepen.io/etoneja/pen/oNxgrQN - look through it, maybe it helps you to figure out whats wrong in your case. Maybe you can try change it to `max-content !important`

Comment: Yes max-content was exactly what I needed

Comment: Ok, nice! To close theme: i assume you get warning with `fit-content` because it waits you to specify length of content (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).

Comment: Well I am getting the same warning with max-content too, but id does what I want